# SpinnerDateModel in JTable

Tags: java, swing, date, jtable, jspinner

Using several examples from various sources I've developed my take on Spinner based JTable editor. Everything works fine and dandy until I press something in other columns with other types of data. Then table freezes and Console throws IllegalArgumentException. I think problem is with *getTableCellEditorComponent()* method and illegal values which are somehow passed to Spinner. However, I don't get the mechanism fully. Could someone explain where the problem is and how to solve it?

```
public class SpinnerEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor, TableCellRenderer{
private JSpinner editSpinner, renderSpinner;
private JTable table;
private String[] list;
private Border originalBorder;

public SpinnerEditor(JTable table, int column, Font font){

    SpinnerDateModel hourModel = new SpinnerDateModel();  
    editSpinner = new JSpinner(hourModel);
    editSpinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(editSpinner, "HH:mm"));
    editSpinner.setFont(font);
    renderSpinner = new JSpinner(hourModel);
    renderSpinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(renderSpinner, "HH:mm"));
    originalBorder = editSpinner.getBorder();
    editSpinner.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE));
    this.table = table;
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).setCellEditor(this);
}

public Object getCellEditorValue(){

    Date date=(Date)editSpinner.getValue();
    SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    return format.format(date);
}

public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    String dateInString = "11-03-1990 13:00:00";
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = sdf.parse(dateInString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
     if (value == null) {
         editSpinner.setValue(date);
     }
    if (value != null) editSpinner.setValue(value);
    return editSpinner;
}

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column){
     return renderSpinner;
}

public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject evt){
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: You were given a link to some working code in your last question. Why are you not using that code?

Comment: Well, I actually use big part of that code from previous question. However, my program deals with several different data types and Date class especially. So, maybe due to that change the code stopped working properly (or maybe I have stripped some essential part).

Comment: `maybe I have stripped some essential part` - that was my point. Go back to the working code and figure out what you changed to make it stop working. Remove one line at a time if you feel the code needs to be changed. Then if it stops working you know where the problem is. Don't ask us to do the debugging for you.